# Seeing other mesh vertices while editing another one?

Tags: vertices

How can I make it so that I'm able to see the vertices of other meshes while I'm editing other ones, if it's possible?

What I'm trying to accomplish is seeing one mesh's vertices while working on a separate mesh entirely.

So is this possible?

Comment: Multi object editing is included inf 2.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you pointed out that you want to

> see[] one mesh's vertices while working on a separate mesh

I guess MultiEdit isn't your desired choice.

As far as I know there is no way to show all the vertices of an object while not in edit mode. However, you can **visualize all edges**, which at least is another way of seeing where the vertices are.

Here's how to make the edges always visible: Check the Edges box in the Display panel in the Object tab.
[image: enable edges visibility]

Comment: Thanks quil and moon. That helps some. I can at least see the points where vertices would be created, so that's useful enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to display the edges, you can select the object, go in the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Display* > Click on *Draw All Edges* and *Maximum Draw Type* > *Wire*.

But otherwise there is an addon called **MultiEdit**: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtxbhxxw9qriti2/MultiEdit_1_0.zip?dl=0

Download and install it, then select both your objects and, in the left panel (activated with <kbd>T</kbd>) > *Tools* > *Multiple Objects Editing* > click on the *MultiEdit Enter* button. Click on the *MultiEdit Exit* when you have finished.

[image]